# Can't get to any Vagrant sites on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, homestead

I'm on a fresh install of Ubuntu Budgie 17.04, and have only installed updates, Virtual Box, and Vagrant.

I've tried to go through the set up on https://box.scotch.io as well as the set up for https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead.

They both successfully run vagrant up with no errors being thrown. However if I try to go to http://192.168.33.10/ for the default Scotchbox page or try to go to the default homestead.app (it is in my hosts file) the page just loads forever and says connection timed out.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot and fix this?

Edit: I can go to localhost:8000 and see my vagrant dummy index.html file... but still can't get there by using homestead.app or 192.168.10.10

Edit 2: Not sure if this is really a good solution, but at the top of my hosts file I had this line...

```
127.0.1.1 xander-pc
```

And deleting this line has fixed all my vagrant issues. Is there any negative side effects that will happen from deleting this line?

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use a non-vagrant ready image, then you should specify hostname in `.Vagrantfile` before initialises the server.

```
config.vm.hostname "your-intentend-guest-hostname"
```

By default, Vagrant will attempt to connect to the guest via SSH via name "Vagrant". So if you didn't tell Vagrant about another name you use,   Vagrant simply tell the guest SSH server it attempts connection to a hostname call 'Vagrant'. When the server checks the hostname and returns something else that the Vagrant ssh client simply rejects.  If you remove that line as mentioned, then Vagrant has no quarrel with it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with all vagrant boxes and found the solution to be:

**removing the second line in the /etc/hosts file**
 like you suggested just uncomment or remove the line containing:

     `127.0.1.1 [computer-name]`

**Installing net-tools:**
It seems like ubuntu 17.04 is not installing the package `net-tools` anymore.

So installing them via 

     `sudo apt-get install net-tools`

and it should work again.

Comment: thanks. I had the exact similar issue and this resolved my problem.